# Remove item from list in jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This has been asked sometime before but I'm not able to figure out the problem looking at there solution.

So I've got a HTML and jquery code which add rows like this:-

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        window.VendorDetail = '@Url.Action("GetQuoteVendorDetail", "Technical")';
        window.SaveItemDetails = '@Url.Action("SaveItemDetails", "Technical")';

        $('#divQuoteDetails').hide();

        //1. Add new row
    $("#addNew").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $tableBody = $("#lotTable");
        var $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last");
        var $trNew = $trLast.clone();

        var suffix = $trNew.find(':input:first').attr('name').match(/\d+/);
        $trNew.find("td:last").html('<a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>');
        $.each($trNew.find(':input'), function (i, val) {
            // Replaced Name
            var oldN = $(this).attr('name');
            var newN = oldN.replace('[' + suffix + ']', '[' + (parseInt(suffix) + 1) + ']');
            $(this).attr('name', newN);
            //Replaced value
            var type = $(this).attr('type');
            if (type.toLowerCase() == "text") {
                $(this).attr('value', '');
            }

            // If you have another Type then replace with default value
            $(this).removeClass("input-validation-error");

        });
        $trLast.after($trNew);

        // Re-assign Validation
        //var form = $("form")
        //    .removeData("validator")
        //    .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
        //$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
    });

 
    // 2. Remove
        $('.remove').on("click", "a", function (e) {
            debugger;
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });

});
```

```html
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12"><a href="#" id="addNew" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Add Lot Details</a></div>
                <table id="lotTable" class="table table-responsive table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="bg-cyan">
                            <th>Lot Name</th>
                            <th>Lot Date</th>
                            <th>Lot Qty</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.LotTable)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input name="LotName" id="LotName" type="text" value="@item.LotName" class="form-control" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input name="LotDate" id="LotWiseDate" type="text" value="@item.LotWiseDate" class="form-control NoEndDate forSingle" readonly="readonly" autocomplete="off" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input name="LotQty" id="LotWiseQty" type="text" value="@item.LotWiseQty" class="form-control" />
                                </td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Now the problem is although the rows are adding properly I'm not able to remove them. Even the click event is not calling the Remove function.

Comment: The function is not getting called itself. I'm trying to put a debugger but it's not being hit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1.** You should listen to the event when the DOM element has been rendered by moving the event `remove` onclick into inside `$("#addNew").click` like below.

```
       //$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
        
         // 2. Remove
        $('.remove').on("click", function (e) {
           console.log("Removed");
           $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });
```

Read the following post to have a better understanding.

[Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

**2.** You've already listened `.remove` an element so you no need to listen `on("click", "a",` again.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        window.VendorDetail = '@Url.Action("GetQuoteVendorDetail", "Technical")';
        window.SaveItemDetails = '@Url.Action("SaveItemDetails", "Technical")';

        $('#divQuoteDetails').hide();

        //1. Add new row
    $("#addNew").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $tableBody = $("#lotTable");
        var $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last");
        var $trNew = $trLast.clone();

        var suffix = $trNew.find(':input:first').attr('name').match(/\d+/);
        $trNew.find("td:last").html('<a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>');
        $.each($trNew.find(':input'), function (i, val) {
            // Replaced Name
            var oldN = $(this).attr('name');
            var newN = oldN.replace('[' + suffix + ']', '[' + (parseInt(suffix) + 1) + ']');
            $(this).attr('name', newN);
            //Replaced value
            var type = $(this).attr('type');
            if (type.toLowerCase() == "text") {
                $(this).attr('value', '');
            }

            // If you have another Type then replace with default value
            $(this).removeClass("input-validation-error");

        });
        $trLast.after($trNew);

        // Re-assign Validation
        //var form = $("form")
        //    .removeData("validator")
        //    .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
        //$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
        
         // 2. Remove
        $('.remove').on("click", function (e) {
           console.log("Removed");
           $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12"><a href="#" id="addNew" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Add Lot Details</a></div>
                <table id="lotTable" class="table table-responsive table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="bg-cyan">
                            <th>Lot Name</th>
                            <th>Lot Date</th>
                            <th>Lot Qty</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.LotTable)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input name="LotName" id="LotName" type="text" value="@item.LotName" class="form-control" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input name="LotDate" id="LotWiseDate" type="text" value="@item.LotWiseDate" class="form-control NoEndDate forSingle" readonly="readonly" autocomplete="off" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input name="LotQty" id="LotWiseQty" type="text" value="@item.LotWiseQty" class="form-control" />
                                </td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: Really? You cannot remove row? Please double-check, please.

Comment: I've been checking since yesterday. This is cracking my head. It should not be so hard to do. Still I can't figure out the problem, :(

Comment: Check again and give me your feedback. It works fine for me.

Comment: Oh Yeah, I missed the first line of your answer. It does work. Thanks!!

Comment: Can you pls explain this?

Comment: 1. You should listen to event when the DOM element has been rendered. 2. you've already listen `.remove` an element so no need to listen `.a` again. Besides, it's incorrect syntax

Comment: But why we need to keep it inside the $("#addNew").click event?

Comment: **You should listen to event when the DOM element has been rendered**

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
$("td").on("click", "a.remove", function(){
        debugger;
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the post [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

You can also listen to event like

```
$(staticAncestors).on(eventName, dynamicChild, function() {});
```

Then your jquery looks like this

```
// 2. Remove
$('#lotTable').on("click", '.remove', function (e) {
   $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        window.VendorDetail = '@Url.Action("GetQuoteVendorDetail", "Technical")';
        window.SaveItemDetails = '@Url.Action("SaveItemDetails", "Technical")';

        $('#divQuoteDetails').hide();

        //1. Add new row
    $("#addNew").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $tableBody = $("#lotTable");
        var $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last");
        var $trNew = $trLast.clone();

        var suffix = $trNew.find(':input:first').attr('name').match(/\d+/);
        $trNew.find("td:last").html('<a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>');
        $.each($trNew.find(':input'), function (i, val) {
            // Replaced Name
            var oldN = $(this).attr('name');
            var newN = oldN.replace('[' + suffix + ']', '[' + (parseInt(suffix) + 1) + ']');
            $(this).attr('name', newN);
            //Replaced value
            var type = $(this).attr('type');
            if (type.toLowerCase() == "text") {
                $(this).attr('value', '');
            }

            // If you have another Type then replace with default value
            $(this).removeClass("input-validation-error");

        });
        $trLast.after($trNew);

        // Re-assign Validation
        //var form = $("form")
        //    .removeData("validator")
        //    .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
        //$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
    });
    
    // 2. Remove
        $('#lotTable').on("click", '.remove', function (e) {
           $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12"><a href="#" id="addNew" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Add Lot Details</a></div>
                <table id="lotTable" class="table table-responsive table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="bg-cyan">
                            <th>Lot Name</th>
                            <th>Lot Date</th>
                            <th>Lot Qty</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input name="LotName" id="LotName" type="text" value="@item.LotName" class="form-control" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input name="LotDate" id="LotWiseDate" type="text" value="@item.LotWiseDate" class="form-control NoEndDate forSingle" readonly="readonly" autocomplete="off" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input name="LotQty" id="LotWiseQty" type="text" value="@item.LotWiseQty" class="form-control" />
                                </td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: This can also be done. But I'll go with the previous solution.